# Exponential Decay Pattern

Tags: exponential-function

I have the pattern below:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
  age (years) & remainder \\\hline
  0 & 100\% \\
  20 & 66.7\% \\
  100 & 50\% \\
  300 & 40\% \\
  1000 & 33.3\%
\end{array}
$$

I need an equation which indicates above decaying pattern.

Comment: You're not going to get one unless you try it yourself here...?

Comment: Try and explain to us what your problem is, what you already tried, and what is the context of this problem (the maths you're studying right now). Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Have you tried plotting it in a spreadsheet?  Excel will do an exponential fit and give you the parameters.

Comment: plot remainder vs.  log (year)

Comment: @GCab: the first value is problematic.

Comment: An exponential model such as $a+be^{-ct}$ does not work well, the initial decay is too large. Can you give more hints about the underlying physical model ? Do you know the final value ?